# Table Header Row not repeated when using subreports inside tables in Sql Server Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I would like to split a dataset in two, so I thought of using 2 subreports inside a table to be side by side. Each subreport contains a table showing either even or odd rows. My problem is that the header of the main report is not repeated. In the Row Groups section I have set the properties of the Static group to "True" for RepeatOnNewPage and "After" for KeepWithGroup, but this hasn't done what I thought it would do.

http://i1348.photobucket.com/albums/p729/Konstantinos_Papakonstantinou/c7999fb3-e6a0-4070-a4c2-aac962c17c07_zpsc66f4d91.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using tables inside tables through this excellent [article](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2012/11/01/creating-multiple-column-reports/).